# Implementing ARCore with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, arcore

I'm starting to play around with ARCore with Xamarin, and am running into some issues. I see two sample projects:

1. https://github.com/dotMorten/ARCore.Xamarin

This is outdated, when I update all of the Xamarin packages to the latest, it results in a lot of build errors. It seems that there were a ton of breaking api changes since this was developed.

2. https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/ARCore

This is up to date (I think), but their sample "HelloAR" solution doesn't build. It references a JavaGL project, which is supposed to have an obj.jar file but it doesn't exist on [github](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/ARCore/samples/JavaGL).

> /Users/justintoth/Downloads/XamarinComponents-master/Android/ARCore/samples/JavaGL/CSC:
>   Error CS1566: Error reading resource 'obj.jar' -- 'Could not find a
>   part of the path
>   "/Users/justintoth/Downloads/XamarinComponents-master/Android/ARCore/externals/obj.jar".'
>   (CS1566) (JavaGL)

I'm wondering how others are getting started with ARCore with Xamarin? Were you able to get past the build errors above, or are you using a different Xamarin project?

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/augmented-reality-xamarin-android-arcore/

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, worked like a charm. That's what I get for not reading the ReadMe file... If you want to copy/paste your comment as the answer, I'll accept.

Comment: The current link is : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/augmented-reality-xamarin-android-arcore/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Obj.jar` is in "external" jar via http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/de/javagl/obj

You can look at the cake build file to see how it is downloaded/used as it is contained in the component, same for the `arcore.aar`.

#### [XamarinComponents/Android/ARCore/build.cake](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/blob/69889c7e9b3387d067b403d643aa3ff478ed5f51/Android/ARCore/build.cake)

```
~~~
var AAR_VERSION = "1.0.0";
var AAR_URL = string.Format("https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/ar/core/{0}/core-{0}.aar", AAR_VERSION);
var OBJ_VERSION = "0.2.1";
var OBJ_URL = string.Format("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/de/javagl/obj/{0}/obj-{0}.jar", OBJ_VERSION);
~~~
```

Comment: The cake build file is not working for me. Downloads fail: Error downloading 'XamarinComponent.1.1.0.65' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarincomponent/1.1.0.65/xamarincomponent.1.1.0.65.nupkg'.
crypt32.dll
Error downloading 'XamarinComponent.1.1.0.65' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarincomponent/1.1.0.65/xamarincomponent.1.1.0.65.nupkg'.
crypt32.dll
Install failed. Rolling back...